# ExecutorService submit() - How to make it non blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking

I'm trying to make the following code non-blocking.
I'm using ExecutorService.

In my constructor:

```
this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

then I add all the items I want to run in parallel to a list:

```
   Future<Map.Entry<Location, SomeData>> result = this.executor.submit(new Sender(entry));
   resultList.add(result);
```

Then I loop on that list and use the `get()` function of `Future` in order to execute each task - which appears to be blocking:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {

        Future<Map.Entry<Location, SomeData>> result = resultList.get(i);

        try {
            logger.info("[Start] Task" + sendQueue.get(i).getKey() + "-" + i);
            entry = result.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Interrupted error", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("Thread Execution error", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Send Error", e);
        }

        if (entry == null) {
            logger.error("Telemetry Send Error");
            return;
        }

        logger.info("[Success] Task" + entry.getKey() + "-" + i);
    }
```

Sender call():

```
@Override
    public Map.Entry<Location, Data> call() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return this.entry;
    }
```

Then my program runs all this code somewhere like this:

```
public void myMainProgram() {
    System.out.println("Started");
    this.startAllExecutorTasks();
    System.out.println("Ended - More code that should run without waiting for the tasks");
}
```

I expect the `startAllExecutorTasks` method (which runs all the code above) to be non-blocking, which means the "started" and "Ended" prints should be printed one after the other. I want my program to continue working although my executor running his own tasks.

Any idea how I can make my thread executor code non blocking?

Comment: Future's `get` blocks and waits. You can check if a result is available using `isDone`.

Comment: Why do you wait for the results with the calling thread when you want the whole thing to be executed async? Either execute the whole thing by a seperate task/thread or get the results later.

Comment: @akuzminykh An `ExecutorService` can be used to restrict concurrency, similar to the UI event thread.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect the startAllExecutorTasks method (which runs all the code above) to be non-blocking, which means the "started" and "Ended" prints should be printed one after the other.

The reason why it's blocking is because you wait for the results from the `Future`s.

If you want to make the method call not block, while also still have it wait for the results, make the method call in a background thread:

```
void startAllExecutorTasksInBackground() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
             .submit(this::startAllExecutorTasks);
}

public void myMainProgram() {
    System.out.println("Started");
    this.startAllExecutorTasksInBackground();
    System.out.println("Ended - More code that should run without waiting for the tasks");
}
```